# In Latex beamer, how would one draw a large arrow on a slide

Tags: latex, beamer

I am using a latex to create a slide show. I was wondering if there are ways to make a big arrow that points from some specific location on the top of my slide do somewhere in the bottom of the slide. I want to point out that two things are the same.

I am aware of Tikz : Problem is that one of the two things I point to is a maths formula (in text), and the other one is a number in a table (\begin{tabular} environment).

So I was wondering if there was just some way to a draw an arrow over the current slide, that points from location x to location y?

Comment: tikzmark package to the rescue!

Comment: Can you make a [mre] so we don't have to start from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `tikzmark` library:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\tikzmark{start}\lipsum[2]\tikzmark{end}


\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[red,thick,->] (pic cs:start) -- (pic cs:end);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot that is precisely what I wanted to do!

Comment: @mnr you could have had this hours ago if you would have provided a [mre]